# How can you find out which .dylib file contains a certain boost functionality

Tags: c++, boost, symbols

I am using Boost in an Xcode and have to add the .dylib files that contain the functionality that is used. Some of them makes perfect sense from the naming e.g. libboost_signals.dylib for using signals. But i can't find the .dylib to include for stuff like mpl and Boost.type_traits. I have searched the web but it didn't give me anything. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of boost libraries are header only. That means that they consist only of header files, so they have no dylib's (so's on linux and dll's on windows). If you deal with templates you can't compile them beforehand: you have to provide source code which will be instantiated with proper types and compiled in-to a object file which uses them.

mpl and type_traits are header only so you don't need to add any additional dylib's to your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore symbols inside libraries using nm, for example, try running `nm libboost_signals.dylib`